# What am I doing wrong in this mySQL foreign key set up?

Tags: mysql, sql

**SOLVED! Answered in separate post below**

"Cannot add foreign key constraint"

This occurs ONLY when in table `Consist_of` I use the code:

```
INDEX trade_name (trade_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (trade_name)
    REFERENCES Drug(trade_name)  
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (pre_no, dssn, pname, trade_name)
```

If I  take out `trade_name` from `PRIMARY KEY ()` and remove the `INDEX` to `CASCADE,` code, then my stuff successfully compiles. All I'm trying to do is have it so I can enter in `Drug`s with the same name, and have the unique key be the combination of `pname` and `trade_name`

all code:

```
 CREATE TABLE Doctor (
dssn INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
dname VARCHAR(30),
specialty VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Prescription (
  pre_no INT(6) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  dssn INT(6) UNSIGNED,
  INDEX dssn (dssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (dssn)
    REFERENCES Doctor(dssn)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  pdate DATETIME
);

CREATE Table Ph_company (
  pname varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  phone varchar(12)
);

CREATE Table Drug (
  pname varchar(30), 
  trade_name VARCHAR(30),
  formula VARCHAR(30),
  INDEX pname (pname),
  FOREIGN KEY (pname)
    REFERENCES Ph_company(pname)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
   key(pname, trade_name)
);



CREATE Table Consist_of (
  pre_no INT(6) UNSIGNED,
  dssn INT(6) UNSIGNED,
  pname varchar(30), 
  trade_name VARCHAR(30),
  INDEX pre_no (pre_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (pre_no)
           REFERENCES Prescription(pre_no)
           ON DELETE CASCADE,
  INDEX dssn (dssn),
  FOREIGN KEY (dssn)
           REFERENCES Prescription(dssn)
           ON DELETE CASCADE,
  INDEX pname (pname),
  FOREIGN KEY (pname)
    REFERENCES Drug(pname)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  INDEX trade_name (trade_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (trade_name)
    REFERENCES Drug(trade_name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (pre_no, dssn, pname, trade_name)

);
```

Comment: The referenced key must be unique or primary key:change trade_name to unique in drug table http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6b150

Comment: @mihai are you sure about that :)

Comment: Of course this is the theory,why would mysql allow key references to a non unique column nobody knows.

Comment: @mihai see my just created answer. It is for fast lookup, but there is no requirement for uniqueness

Comment: @Drew Your answer doenst say why mysql allows non unique keys,every other db doesnt.\

Comment: @Mihai perhaps you like the answer now. All I am saying is that your comment on uniqueness is not accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures that after 2 hours of head-banging, I figure out the solution (I think) 2 minutes after I ask you guys here.

I added

`INDEX trade_name (trade_name),
   key(pname, trade_name)`

to the end of `Drug`'s creation code, and it works now, allowing me to enter in duplicate drug names.

Comment: This happens to me so often, I spend hours on an issue, post a StackOverflow question and then *bang* I discover the answer of my own volition.

Answer (score 0):

Since the primary key in DRUG is a composite key consisting of 2 fields, you must set up the foreign key the same way. So instead of declaring 2 foreign keys (1 for pname and another for trade_name), do this instead:

```
FOREIGN KEY ('pname','trade_name') 
    REFERENCES Drug('pname','trade_name')
```